# How can I get the captions and images aligned?

Tags: graphics, grids

I have this code

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 119 Position with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T119PosiSin.eps}} &
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 118 Position with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T118PosiSin.eps}} &
\\
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 119 Current with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T119CurrSin.eps}} &
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 118 Current with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T118CurrSin.eps}} &
\\
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 119 Position with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T119PosiSqu.eps}} &
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 118 Position with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T118PosiSqu.eps}} &
\\
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 119 Current with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T119CurrSqu.eps}} &
\subfloat[$T_s$ = 118 Current with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{T118CurrSqu.eps}} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{4 x 2}
\end{figure}
```

This leads to the image attached where the images and the captions are not aligned properly. Does anyone know how I can make it so that they become aligned correctly?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To mark some part of your post as code, put it in the cursor and press the `{}` button. And please complete your code such that it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` such that those who are willing to help do not have to guess which packages you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `tabular` is defined with two columns, but you're using three columns in the `tabular` body:

```
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
  <first column> & <second column> & <third column>
  \\
  <first column> & <second column> & <third column>
  \\
  % ...
\end{tabular}
```

Drop the second `&` so you're using only the columns specified.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{ c c }
    \subfloat[$T_s = 119$ Position with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-a}} &
    \subfloat[$T_s = 118$ Position with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-b}}
    \\
    \subfloat[$T_s = 119$ Current with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-a}} &
    \subfloat[$T_s = 118$ Current with sine]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-b}}
    \\
    \subfloat[$T_s = 119$ Position with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-b}} &
    \subfloat[$T_s = 118$ Position with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-a}}
    \\
    \subfloat[$T_s = 119$ Current with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-b}} &
    \subfloat[$T_s = 118$ Current with square]{\includegraphics[width = 2in]{example-image-a}} 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{$2 \times 4$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```